# Put NSDictionary data in ModelObject

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I receive a JSON object (converted to NSDictionary) which I want to put it into my model object.

i tried this one

```
  {
        Description = "Desc.";
        EndTime = "2014-06-25T05:35:00";
        Id = "";
        IsActive = 1;
        StartTime = "2014-06-25T05:30:00";
        Title = "Test appointment";
    },
        {
        Description = Qww;
        EndTime = "2014-06-26T02:58:00";
        Id = "";
        IsActive = 1;
        StartTime = "2014-06-26T01:58:00";
        Title = q;
    }
```

I want to store it into my model object NSobject. but only get first dictioanry

i have tried this one

```
     MyAppoinmentModel * modelObj;

    modelObj =[[MyAppoinmentModel alloc]init];
```

modelobj =[[MyAppoinmentModel alloc]init];

```
    for(NSMutableDictionary * dic in array)
    {

        NSString * strTitle =[dic valueForKey:@"Title"];
        NSString * strDescription =[dic valueForKey:@"Description"];
        NSString * strStartTime =[dic valueForKey:@"StartTime"];
        NSString * strEndTime =[dic valueForKey:@"EndTime"];
        NSString * strMeetingDate =[dic valueForKey:@"MeetingDate"];
        NSString * strIsActive =[dic valueForKey:@"IsActive"];


        modelobj.Titlestr=strTitle;
        modelobj.Descriptionstr=strDescription;
        modelobj.StartTimeStr=strStartTime;
        modelobj.EndTimeStr=strEndTime;
        modelobj.Daystr=strMeetingDate;

    }
```

Where may i wrong can u help me to do this one.

Comment: Two issues. First, you never create a new `modelobj` in your for loop, so you will actually only ever have `modelobj = [array lastObject]`. Second, is your array even populating? We don't have your code on how you're parsing the JSON.

Comment: You don't receive a JSON object/NSDictionary, you receive a JSON array/NSArray, containing multiple objects/NSDictionarys.

Comment: i get that json array now i want to put it into my obj model. hopw may i do this

Comment: Iterate on the array and create the multiple objects, placing them in an array.

Comment: Hint:  Create a `initWithDictonary` method to init the objects.

Comment: can u give me one sample code. i am very thankful for that.

Comment: No.  If you can't handle this then you should not be programming in Objective-C.

Comment: I've added code for you @Jitendra but with how many questions you've been answering for iOS this should be basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that should work. I don't know what the key is that is above the modelObjects (include that next time if you want a code sample response) so I just assumed it's "models".

I'm adding all the `modelObj` to a `NSMutableArray` so that you have access to all `modelObj` afterwords, since there is no guarantee that there will only be one `NSDictionary` in the JSON return. This uses Hot Licks's suggestion of creating a method to create each `MyAppointmentModel`.

NOTE: You forgot about the IsActive and ID parts. I've stubbed them in my solution, but you should add them to your code.

```
  NSArray* jsonSerialArray = [NSJSONSerialization
         JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse
         options:0
         error:&error];

  NSArray *JSON = [jsonSerialArray objectForKey:@"models"];
  NSMutableArray *modelObjArray = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (NSDictionary *dict in JSON)
  {      
    [modelObjArray addObject:[self createModelObjectWithDictionary:dict]];
  }
  do something with modelObjArray
}

-(MyAppointmentModel *)createModelObjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
  MyAppoinmentModel *modelObj = [[MyAppoinmentModel alloc] init];    

  modelobj.Titlestr=[dict valueForKey:@"Title"];
  modelobj.Descriptionstr=[dict valueForKey:@"Description"];
  modelobj.StartTimeStr=[dict valueForKey:@"StartTime"];
  modelobj.EndTimeStr=[dict valueForKey:@"EndTime"];
  modelobj.MeetingDate=[dict valueForKey:@"MeetingDate"];
  modelobj.IsActive=[dict valueForKey:@"IsActive"];
  modelobj.ID=[dict valueForKey:@"ID"];

  return modelobj;
}
```