# Get json data and stored it into nsobject (Model Object )

Tags: ios, objective-c

here I get the json array it contains multiple dictionary.

```
(
    {
        text = Aaa;
        title = 1;
    },
    {
        text = Bbb;
        title = 2;
    }
)
```

I tried this one

```
for(NSDictionary * dic in array)
    {

        NSString * strTitle =[dic valueForKey:@"Title"];

        NSString * strDescription =[dic valueForKey:@"Description"];

        NSString * strSatartDate =[dic valueForKey:@"StartTime"];

        NSString * strEndDate =[dic valueForKey:@"EndTime"];

        NSString * strDay =[dic valueForKey:@"MeetingDate"];

        NSString * strEPid =[dic valueForKey:@"EPId"];

        objModel.Titlestr=strTitle;
        objModel.Descriptionstr=strDescription;
        objModel.StartTimeStr=strSatartDate;
        objModel.EndTimeStr=strEndDate;
        objModel.Daystr=strDay;
        objModel.EPId=strEPid;
    }
```

so herev i want to generate obj with 2 dictionary but this will not work for jme.

I want to put it into NSObject how may I do this.

Comment: You need to store it into an NSArray

Comment: how.. can u give me some sample code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Put NSDictionary data in ModelObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416913/put-nsdictionary-data-in-modelobject)

Comment: Why did you open a second copy of the exact same question an hour after the first???

Answer (score 0):

All objects inherit from NSObject in Objective C.

Here's how you parse that data.

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization:data //data is NSData type
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                    error:nil];

for (NSDictionary * data in jsonArray) {
    NSString * text = data[@"text"];
    int title = [data[@"title"]intValue];

    NSLog(@"text=%@ and title=%d", text, title);
}
```

Output:

```
text=Aaa and title=1
text=Baa and title=2
```

If your model property is supposed to hold multiple value the you cannot use NSString.

You will need an Array instead, a mutable one so you can append values to it

```
for(NSDictionary * dic in array){

    NSString * strTitle =[dic valueForKey:@"Title"];
    NSString * strDescription =[dic valueForKey:@"Description"];
    NSString * strSatartDate =[dic valueForKey:@"StartTime"];
    NSString * strEndDate =[dic valueForKey:@"EndTime"];
    NSString * strDay =[dic valueForKey:@"MeetingDate"];
    NSString * strEPid =[dic valueForKey:@"EPId"];



    [objModel.Titlestr addObject:strTitle];  
    [objModel.Descriptionstr addObject:strDescription]; 
    [objModel.StartTimeStr addObject:strSatartDate]; 
    [objModel.EndTimeStr addObject:strEndDate]; 
    [objModel.Daystr addObject:strDay]; 
    [objModel.EPId addObject:strEPid]; 

}
```

Comment: but when it shift the second dictionary it will replace the previous data

Comment: @Jitendra, what do you mean, what is the log showing u

Comment: i get the last data only into that object

Comment: I see your code, you are overwriting the model property at each iteration thats why you get the last iteration value, change your model so you can append data at each loop iteration

Comment: how may i proceed for this

Comment: you are still using nsstring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56308/discussion-between-meda-and-jitendra).